# Check if a value exists in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

How can I check if a value exists in an `ArrayList`?

```
List<CurrentAccount> lista = new ArrayList<CurrentAccount>();

CurrentAccount conta1 = new CurrentAccount("Alberto Carlos", 1052);
CurrentAccount conta2 = new CurrentAccount("Pedro Fonseca", 30);
CurrentAccount conta3 = new CurrentAccount("Ricardo Vitor", 1534);
CurrentAccount conta4 = new CurrentAccount("João Lopes", 3135);

lista.add(conta1);
lista.add(conta2);
lista.add(conta3);
lista.add(conta4);

Collections.sort(lista);

System.out.printf("Bank Accounts:" + "%n");
Iterator<CurrentAccount> itr = lista.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    CurrentAccount element = itr.next();
    System.out.printf(element + " " + "%n");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 379, accepted):

Just use [ArrayList.contains(desiredElement)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).  For example, if you're looking for the conta1 account from your example, you could use something like:

```
if (lista.contains(conta1)) {
    System.out.println("Account found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Account not found");
}
```

**Edit:**
Note that in order for this to work, you will need to properly override the [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [hashCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods. If you are using Eclipse IDE, then you can have these methods generated by first opening the source file for your `CurrentAccount` object and the selecting `Source > Generate hashCode() and equals()...`

Comment: equals() method should be overridden in CurrentAccount to determinate when they are the same object

Comment: In that case hashcode() needs to be overridden, too. Per hashcode() contract equal objects must have equal hashcodes.

Comment: @zockman sure you're right, though I think overriding equals is even more important in this case because if not a CurrentAccount object may not be the same even when all their attributes have the same value. But I do agree in overriding hashcode() too.

Comment: Is there a version that compares object refferences?

Comment: What if I cannot override equals . since object is in another library . Now how can I achieve this?

Comment: @user1846749: That seems like a topic for another question. (Sorry to pass the buck, but I don't program in Java these days.)

Comment: its not working, however overriding equals method it worked for me.

Comment: @user1846749 did you find a way to do this without overriding equals?
I'm attempting to use it in VBA which also utilizes an ArrayList, but you can't override equals in VBA... (that I know of.)

Answer (score 54):

Better to use a `HashSet` than an `ArrayList` when you are checking for existence of a value.

Java docs for `HashSet` says

> This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)

`ArrayList.contains()` might have to iterate the whole list to find the instance you are looking for.

Answer (score 27):

We can use `contains` method to check if an item exists if we have provided the implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` else object reference will be used for equality comparison. Also in case of a list `contains` is `O(n)` operation where as it is `O(1)` for `HashSet` so better to use later. In Java 8 we can use streams also to check item based on its equality or based on a specific property.

### Java 8

```
CurrentAccount conta5 = new CurrentAccount("João Lopes", 3135);
boolean itemExists = lista.stream().anyMatch(c -> c.equals(conta5)); //provided equals and hashcode overridden
System.out.println(itemExists); // true

String nameToMatch = "Ricardo Vitor";
boolean itemExistsBasedOnProp = lista.stream().map(CurrentAccount::getName).anyMatch(nameToMatch::equals);
System.out.println(itemExistsBasedOnProp); //true
```

Comment: thank you for this amazing answer actually it's a +1 ! I used this part of the code :`boolean itemExistsBasedOnProp = selectedR.stream().map(Request::getDesc).anyMatch(cn::equals);` now I need it to extract that item! is it possible ??

Comment: @maryemneyli use `findAny`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--

Comment: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): `java.util.Collection#stream`

Comment: This Solution also works when we have a List of POJO and we want to check for any value from the set of properties present in the POJO

Answer (score 18):

Please refer to my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909871/how-to-check-in-java-if-set-contains-object-with-some-string-value/22532909#22532909).

There is no need to iterate over the `List`; just override the `equals` method and use `.contains`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object object) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
        result = false;
    } else {
        EmployeeModel employee = (EmployeeModel) object;
        if (this.name.equals(employee.getName()) && this.designation.equals(employee.getDesignation())   && this.age == employee.getAge()) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    EmployeeModel first = new EmployeeModel("Sameer", "Developer", 25);
    EmployeeModel second = new EmployeeModel("Jon", "Manager", 30);
    EmployeeModel third = new EmployeeModel("Priyanka", "Tester", 24);

    List<EmployeeModel> employeeList = new ArrayList<EmployeeModel>();
    employeeList.add(first);
    employeeList.add(second);
    employeeList.add(third);

    EmployeeModel checkUserOne = new EmployeeModel("Sameer", "Developer", 25);
    System.out.println("Check checkUserOne is in list or not");
    System.out.println("Is checkUserOne Preasent = ? " + employeeList.contains(checkUserOne));

    EmployeeModel checkUserTwo = new EmployeeModel("Tim", "Tester", 24);
    System.out.println("Check checkUserTwo is in list or not");
    System.out.println("Is checkUserTwo Preasent = ? " + employeeList.contains(checkUserTwo));

}
```