# Overriding equals method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, equals

So I have a setup like this:

```
interface A{

}
class B implements A{
    public int hashCode() {
    ...
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    ...
    }
}
class C implements A{
    public int hashCode() {
    ...
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    ...
    }
}
class D{
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
}
```

I want to implement an overridden `equals` method for class D that tests that the lists are equal, but for some reason whenever I try to implement that as this:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        final D other = (D) obj;
        if (values == null) {
            if (other.values != null)
                return false;
        }else if (!values.equals(other.values))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

but I believe that this calls `Object`'s `equals` method where it calls `values.equals(other.values)`, because it is not behaving correctly.

What can I do to make `D`'s `equals` method behave correctly?

Comment: Hello refer this 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909871/how-to-check-in-java-if-set-contains-object-with-some-string-value/22532909#22532909  

I answered there with example.

Comment: You need explain the problem more clearly. What is `VSequence`? What is `values`? How are you calling the `equals` method? What is the behavior you are seeing that is wrong? Post a [minimal and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I call the `equals` method from class D, and the behavior seems to be that it calls `Object`'s `equals` method instead of the method for each  subclass of `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equals()` is the predefined method which is belongs to `Object` class. Remember java is the Object oriented programming language which means that `equals()` method is applicable to every java class implicitely. you have not use the predefined method names as your custom methods.

Inorder to simulatte the `equals()` you need to change the signature, like this,

```
public boolean equals_simulation(final Object obj) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IDE such as Eclipse and you don't need to implement custom rules for equality, you can have Eclipse implement the method for you. Just look for the "override equals and hashCode" option. It should be under Source, or Source > refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to override the equals such that you define a comparison factor between the actual lists.

If you use Maven for dependency management, here you can find Apache Commons Lang3 which contains a handy class called ***EqualsBuilder***, very useful for overriding equals method.

Answer (score 0):

Your last comparison should use `Arrays.equals(list, ((D)other).list)` to compare all array elements. Is `VSequence` actually `D`? Then you can drop the cast to `D`.

Answer (score 0):

`equals` method is available from `Object` class. So it is available in all the concrete Java Classes. The signature of equals method is `public boolean equals(Object equals)`.

Also, `equals` method should work in tandem with `hashcode` method for checking the equality. Its robust way for confirming.