# find the 1st occurrence without using loop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an object class named `Store` which has an attribute "year":

```
public class Store{
     public int year;
     ...
}
```

Then, in another class I got a list of Store :

```
List<Store> stores = getAllStores();
```

I would like to get from the list the 1st occurrence of store whose year is 2002 without using `for` loop or `while` loop. Is it possible?

Comment: Will that method return an ordered List ?

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe Java 8 lambda helps.

Comment: You should consider using linq where statement and then doing first or default

Comment: @EhsanUllah: Isn't LINQ a .Net thing?

Comment: You need to You `Collection`. Detail can be found [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404084/find-if-a-value-exists-in-arraylist

Comment: Is your concern performance or syntax?

Comment: Depending on how Store's `equals` method works, you could use `List#indexOf` to find the first occurrence of a particular store.  If the `equals` method is based on just the year, it should work (though it still uses a loop under the covers.

Comment: If you are the one writing the store class consider adding additional information to your object to store the first one of each year for example. Why can't you use a loop ?

Comment: If you only mind the first year, why not using a Map<Integer, Store> and use the year as the key?

Comment: What about the do-while loop?

Comment: @basar if not syntax, then the concern would be to mess with us ;p

Comment: How about `return new Store(){year=2012}` :)

Answer (score 5):

to iterate is human, to recurse divine

Comment: +1 @Thihara for allowing yourself to smile on StackOverflow which is not allowed. Is it ? ;-)

Comment: @HpTerm and @Thihara thanks, it was easier than writing out a custom `ListIterator < Store >` implementation that implemented `next()` recursively

Comment: you made my day also +1 for the obvious.

Comment: Asking myself up to which number of upvotes you will go with such an answer.

Comment: @HpTerm ask not how many upvotes one's answer gets, ask whether it will be accepted. (ps: on the karma account, mine is the only upvote on the question. just saying... ;)

Comment: @Thihara nice contribution yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted something like ReturnTop where year is 2002, which there are 2 conditions underlying.

Is the objects sorted before added into the list? 
Is there any patterns that uniquely identify 2002 or have you consider hashmap?
Have you considered a stack or a queue where 2002 is the first or the last added?