# Duplication of an item in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am storing Identification addresses in my ArrayList. The problem is I am storing it repeatedly.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void storeIDs(final String emailAddress) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("storeIds", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    IDAddresses.add(emailAddress);

    for(int i=0;i<IDAddresses.size();i++)
    {
        editor.putString("value"+i,IDAddresses.get(i));
    }
    editor.putInt("emailListSize",IDAddresses.size());
    editor.apply();
}
```

How do I check if the `emailAddress` already exists in the ArrayList `IDAddresses` and if it exists, then dont store it?

Comment: why not using a `Set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//use this :
if( !IDAddresses.contains(emailAddress) ){

    IDAddresses.add(emailAddress);

}

//instead of just this :
IDAddresses.add(emailAddress);
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you described, `Set` is the datastructure you should choose.

- Set will **not** store duplicated (equals() ) elements, so you don't have to check and add
- If you need check if an element exists in your collection, a `Hashtable` based `Set`　（E.g. `HashSet`) `contains() O(1)` will be faster than `ArrayList.contains() O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   
if(sh.Contains(IDAddresses.get(i)){//do nothing}
else editor.putString("value"+i,IDAddresses.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kent suggested, you should use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for this.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.

```
Set<String> IDAddresses = new HashSet<>();
```

And then:

```
IDAddresses.add(emailAddress);
```

Another way to do this, which is not recommended but if you're going to use `ArrayList` anyways:

```
List<String> noDupes = Lists.newArrayList(Sets.newHashSet(IDAddresses));
```

Basically removes duplicates by converting the `ArrayList` into a `HashSet`. **Uses Guava**.

If you're using Java 8 you can also make use of lamdas:

```
List<String> noDupes= IDAddresses.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ArrayList.contains(desiredElement). For example, if you're looking for the conta1 account from your example, you could use something like:

```
 if (IDAddresses.contains(i)) {
    System.out.println("Account found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Account not found");
}
```

I didn't tried this method.You have to use this method ArrayList.contains(desiredElement)  for checking the value exists in arraylist or not.

Please go through this link [Check if a value exists in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404084/check-if-a-value-exists-in-arraylist)

Comment: Use this if condition inside the for loop .