# See if name exists in arraylist, if it does, ask for new name

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public Event(String name, int numberOfTries) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numberOfTries = numberOfTries;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumberOfTries() {
    return numberOfTries;
}

public String toString() {
    return name + ", " + numberOfTries;
}

public void addEvent() {
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    eventList.add(new Event("Jacob", 5));

    System.out.print("Event name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    boolean match = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
        if (eventList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            match = false;
            if (!match) {
                System.out.println(name + " has already been added\n");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Event name: ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Attempts allowed: ");
    int numberOfTries = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

    eventList.add(new Event(name, numberOfTries));

    System.out.println(name + " added\n");

}
```

When I enter the pre-existing name "Jacob", it goes like this:

"Event name: Jacob
Jacob has already been added

Attempts allowed:"

I want the program to ask me for a new name, since Jacob already exists. 
But I can't seem to go back in the loop.

I don't want to use Maps or anything like that, only ArrayLists.

Comment: first of all: see the problem in these lines? : 
            match = false;
            if (!match) {
                System.out.println(name + " has already been added\n");
            }

Comment: Why not simply use `contains` to check if an element is present in a list, i.e. `eventList.contains(name)`

Comment: I agree with nbokmans. just add an equals that checks only on the name to your Event class. you'll have to create a new Instance of Event with a name to test though

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly: System.out.print("Event name: ");
  String name = scan.nextLine();
  boolean match = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
   if (eventList.contains(name)) ??

Comment: Wrong construction, you are always assigning false inside match found, which probably should be true and there should be some sort of break action on match

Comment: Related: [Check if a value exists in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4404084). See [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1128723) if you want to know how to write a loop that does this (it's about arrays, not ArrayLists, but the loop looks similar).

Comment: Got help from another student: System.out.print("Event name: ");
  String name = scan.nextLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
   if (eventList.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
    System.out.println("Error " + name + " has already been added\n");
    return;

Comment: Hey @Zakan, for future reference, just because we didn't fix your code dump doesn't mean we didn't help you. No need to be ungrateful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't define `match=false;` and then ask `if(!match)`. It is going yo be always true.

Instead, write the if...else statement outside of the loop. And when the loop finishes It will check for the match boolean. `if (!match) { System.out.println(name + " has already been added\n");} else { System.out.println("Event name: "); match = true;}`

Then introduce a loop which checks for match = true so the user can try several times: `while(!match){
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);                      eventList.add(new Event("Jacob", 5)); System.out.print("Event name: "); String name = scan.nextLine(); for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) { if (eventList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) { match = false;  } }
if (!match) { System.out.println(name + " has already been added\n"); eventList.removeLast();} else { System.out.println("Event name: "); match = true;}
}`

Remember to initiallize the match variable as false, before the while checks it.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it with help of another student!

Comment: @Zakan if my answer was right select It as answer please. If not, send the error and I'll solve it

Comment: Hi, I did not try your answer, sorry.